# Python code not dealing with large numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code to extract each digit in a number starting from the right, written in Python.

```
n=int(input())
while (n>0):
    r=n%10
    print(r) // Printing the current value of n
    n=int(n/10)
    print(n) //Printing n after dividing by 10
```

It works well for smaller integers but as the number of digits exceeds a certain limit, the rightmost digits alter themselves. No idea why that happens.
For example,

1. 1234

   ```
   (Current value of n *space* last digit)

   1234 4

   123 3

   12 2

   1 1

   0
   ```
2. 11111111111111111111

   ```
   11111111111111111111 1

   1111111111111111168 8 **-> 'n' changes after n=int(n/10)**

   111111111111111120 0

   ...
   ```

Can't understand why this happens!

Comment: You probably want to use `//` (integer division) instead of `/` (float division), to keep your numbers as integers.

Comment: That works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single `/` in Python 3 does float division.

`11111111111111111111/10` gives you `1.1111111111111112e+18`. This is approximately equal to the non-integer value you get when you divide your starting number by 10.
When this is cast to an int, you get `111111111111111168`.

If you want to do integer division (division with remainder), you should be using the `//` operator.